# Performance on CHOLMOD with structure of matrix

Tags: matlab, time, sparse-matrix, mesh, solver

I have three matrices listed in below.

All of those matrices are generated assembly procedure for FEM.

but different triangulation index (mesh itself is identical, but mesh index is different)

I used MATLAB built-in A\b.

By using spparms, I can see that they all solved via CHOLMOD.

[image: Mesh with optimized index]

[image: Mesh with half optimized index]

[image: Mesh with generated randomly]

All those meshes are the same with different index

They are essentially the same except for the indexing.

However, they showed different solving time.

```
narrow : 109.230693 sec
half   :  61.316282 sec
random : 121.168484 sec
```

random matrix takes more time than other two matrices is reasonable ( because it has very random pattern and has very wide bandwidth

However, I wondered why narrow matrix takes more time to solve than half-narrow matrix

Since they all symmetric and positive definite, MATLAB used CHOLMOD for all of the matrices.

Is there any reason for this kind of phenomenon?